# Is my /etc/hosts file broken?

Tags: localhost

I am not sure why my /etc/hosts file look like this:

[image]
I tried to open it using different editor(vim, sublime, TextEdit). They all look same. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's broken. You have probably imported it from Windows, so you're experimenting UNIX/DOS new line incompatibilities. Maybe you copied/pasted and placed it in `/etc/hosts/`?

I would use VI to get rid of the `\n` and convert them into actual new line chars.

Comment: That is so weird.....I remember it was fine earlier and did not touch this file for a while.......not sure why it becomes like this....i'll try VI then... thanks!

Comment: Alright, so I get rid of the \n, then everything works fine. I mean finally my postgres can connect to localhost and run. thanks!